# Only colour red working in react component styled with tailwind

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm trying to make custom button element using tailwind and react. I don't know why when i'm apllying any color different then red it just doesn't work.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried with many different colors and I really can't find why it's working only with red.

Comment: Tailwind parses your JSX to determine which classes to include in your actual CSS. Dynamically generated classes can't be parsed by Tailwind. (You're probably using the red color somewhere else, so Tailwind knows about it) To make sure that your class *is* included, add it to the `safelist` property in your Tailwind config. Please post code as text, not as images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could:

- Have the entire class in the variable you pass to `props.color` like

  ```
  export default function Button(props) {
    const color = props.color;
    return (
      <button
        className={`… ${color} …`}
       >
  ```

  ```
  <Button color="from-green-600 to-green-900 …">
  ```
- Have a dictionary for `color` to Tailwind class names:

  ```
  export default function Button(props) {
    const color = props.color;
    const DICTIONARY = {
      red: 'from-red-600 to-red-900 …',
      green: 'from-green-600 to-green-900 …',
      // …
    };
    // …
    return (
      <button
        className={`… ${DICTIONARY[color]}`}
       >
  ```
- Use the `style` attribute for truly dynamic colors, if `theme` can be converted to a valid CSS color value (or you could [get the color from Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#referencing-in-java-script)):

  ```
  export default function Button(props) {
    const color = props.color;
    const styles = {
      // Convert from `color` variable
    };
    // …
    return (
      <button
        className={…}
        style={style}
       >
  ```
- [`safelist` the classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes), if you have a limited number of known colors:

  ```js
  module.exports = {
    safelist: [
      { pattern: /^from-(red|green|blue)-600$/ },
      { pattern: /^to-(red|green|blue)-900$/ },
      // …
    ],
    // …
  ];
  ```

Comment: Thank You so much, I made dictionary with colors I need and it works great  <3